# Subtracting references in perl

Tags: perl, reference

I am trying to subtract two set of data that are too large to be in arrays. I would like to subtract them like normal arrays shown below below.

```
@x = (1, 2, 3);
@x2= (2, 3, 4);

my @delta = map { my $diff = $_; map { $diff - $_ } @x2 } @x;
```

to get:

```
1-2
1-3
1-4
2-2
2-3
2-4
```

etc.

I'm currently using this:

```
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;
my $prot_x_var;
my $lipid_x_var;

#this section count the line in a file containing data. $#data is magnitude of the array of data.
for ( my $count = 0; $count <= $#data; ++$count ) {

#this searches the data for a specific string so $protein is not important but to define the string.
    if ( $data[$count] =~ m/\s+$protein\s+/ ) {
        ++$i;    #adds up the $i foreach specific string found
        $prot_x_var = $protein_xyz_coords->[0]->[$i]->{'x'};    #this flips through all the data points.
        #print "$prot_x_var \n";
    }

    #$POPS and $POPC are just use to find a string.
    if ( ( $data[$count] =~ m/\s+$POPS\s+/ ) || ( $data[$count] =~ m/\s+$POPC\s+/ ) ) {
        ++$j;                                                   #same as $i but for a different string
        $lipid_x_var = $lipid_xyz_coords->[1]->[$j]->{'x'};     #same as above
        #print "$lipid_x_var \n";
    }
}
```

I now want to subtract each `$lipid_x_var` or `$lipid_xyz_coords->[1]->[$j]->{'x'}` from each `$prot_x_var` or `$protein_xyz_coords->[0]->[$i]->{'x'}` like the way the above array did. I have a previous question that someone tried helping me with that is similar but now have to come back to using this idea because of the size of the data.

Comment: What's the question? Can't you just do `$protein_xyz_coords->[0]->[$i]->{'x'} - $lipid_xyz_coords->[1]->[$j]->{'x'}`? BTW, you only need to use one arrow in your references -- `$protein_xyz_coords->[0][$i]{'x'}` is equivalent to `$protein_xyz_coords->[0]->[$i]->{'x'}`.

Comment: No the result is ((0 .. 2083) - 0) then it subtracts (2083 - (2084 -34000)) no like the example I gave with the arrays

Comment: I am using perl version 5.10.1 and I do have to have the all arrows or I get an error about not having the arrows.

Comment: The single arrow notation works fine in 5.10.1 -- [see this example running on perl 5.8](http://codepad.org/N1CSyw3N). You have not given any indication of what kind of data is in `$protein_xyz_coords->[0]->[$i]->{'x'}` -- if it isn't a scalar, you need to indicate what it is, because there's no way of telling from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code has to do with your question. I'll just answer the question.

The following is a solution that doesn't store the result in memory.

```
my @x1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @x2 = (2, 3, 4);

for my $x1 (@x1) {
   for my $x2 (@x2) {
      print("$x1-$x2 = ", $x1-$x2, "\n");
   }
}
```

Or if you want an iterator,

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @x1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @x2 = (2, 3, 4);

my $iter = NestedLoops([ \@x1, \@x2 ]);

while (my ($x1, $x2) = $iter->()) {
   print("$x1-$x2 = ", $x1-$x2, "\n");
}
```

Comment: My arrays for '@x1' and '@x2' in your example are too large to start with. I want to use references to do calculation then store the data in to a file or an array at that point. I just want to know how to subtract the References similar to how the arrays are subtracted.

Comment: Do you not understand the code or do you not understand how I am trying to use the references? Let me know how I can make this more understandable.

Comment: You still need the array if you access it through a reference. Your request makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami is right, the reference does not exist unless the array itself exists in memory.

Answer (score 0):

So your arrays are too large to store in memory?  Hmm... I would try putting both of your arrays in files, then read them in line by line, perform the subtraction and print the output to a new file that way you never store any of the full arrays in memory.

ex:

---

```
x1.dat
1
2
3
```

---

```
x2.dat
2
3
4
```

---

```
test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# create output file
open (OUTPUT, '>', 'output.dat') or die "Failed to open output file: $!";

# loop through x1 values
open (X1, '<', 'x1.dat') or die "Failed to get x1 data: $!";
while (<X1>) {

    # get x1 value
    my $x1 = $_;

    # loop through x2 values
    open (X2, '<', 'x2.dat') or die "Failed to get x2 data: $!";
    while (<X2>) {

        # get x2 value
        my $x2 = $_;

        # get difference
        my $diff = $x1 - $x2;

        # store in output file
        print OUTPUT "$diff\n";
    } close X2;
} close X1;

# close output file
close OUTPUT;
```

---

```
output.dat
-1
-2
-3
0
-1
-2
1
0
-1
```

---

This won't store any giant arrays in memory, instead it will just keep track of a simple index into each file.  Judging by the size of your arrays though you may want to add print statements within the loops so you can see that progress is being made (it may take a very long time to process that much data).  Hope this helps!

---

### EDIT:

Even better solution that doesn't involve reopening and closing the X2 file every time through the loop! Use `seek` to reread the file from the start again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# open input files
open (X1, '<', 'x1.dat') or die "Failed to get x1 data: $!";
open (X2, '<', 'x2.dat') or die "Failed to get x2 data: $!";

# create output file
open (OUTPUT, '>', 'output.dat') or die "Failed to open output file: $!";

# loop through x1 values
while (<X1>) {

    # get x1 value
    my $x1 = $_;

    # loop through x2 values
    seek X2, 0, 0;
    while (<X2>) {

        # get x2 value
        my $x2 = $_;

        # get difference
        my $diff = $x1 - $x2;

        # store in output file
        print OUTPUT "$diff\n";
    }
}

# close input files
close X1;
close X2;

# close output file
close OUTPUT;
```